# Accessing external HDD ext3 (Ubuntu/Linux) files from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I took out a sata hard disk from my PC and put it in an adapter case, so that I can read its files through USB ports. This HDD had a double partition (Windows/Ubuntu).

Now I want to access the Ubuntu partitions from another PC with Windows 10. Of course when I plug this in I can only view the original windows 10 partition sector, so I installed Ext2Fsd 0.69. To allow Windows to navigate through the other partition (which is Ext3) I have to click on the program's **Ext2 volume management** button and enable some options, as all tutorials say. The problem is that nothing happens when I click. Just some loading, but the option window won't pop up. I run the program as administrator and also tried doing everything on a different computer, same thing.

The program Ext2read won't work either, since it shows only  a blank window with no paths for files (the output text error-file says:

```
Error Opening \\.\PhysicalDrive2. Error Code 2
No of disks 2
Scanning \\.\PhysicalDrive0
index 0 ID EE size -1 
Scanning \\.\PhysicalDrive1
index 0 ID EE size 976773167
```

Do you know what is going on? Is this the right way to access Ubuntu on a HDD files from Windows?

Comment: Use Paragon's [LinuxFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/): they have a free (as in beer) solution that will become rate-limited after a while: that's a driver instead of an application so you can use any application (E.g. the Windows Explorer) to copy files.  The rate limit is reasonable and still good for personal use...  If that would help you, leave a comment @fabby and I'll post a full answer.

Comment: You're new here: that was just a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best software out there to read EXT2/3/4 BTRFS, ReiserFS, ... under Windows is Paragon's [LinuxFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/): they have a free (as in beer) solution that installs a driver instead of an application so you can use any application (E.g. the Windows Explorer) to copy files: the Ubuntu disks will just automagically become Windows disks.

The only disadvantage of the free beer is that it will become rate-limited after a while: but the rate limit is reasonable and still good for personal use... If you're running this on a server, consider buying it.

**Disclaimer:** This is a personal and subjective opinion: I'm in no way affiliated with Paragon, just have used their software before.